# Creating a Subscriber in python

Tags: ros, python, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I’m trying to create a subscriber using python for this [package](https://github.com/Corpse89Grinder/adaptive_hog_people_tracker.git), following the tutorials that ros provide.
The package already contains a [subscriber](https://github.com/Corpse89Grinder/adaptive_hog_people_tracker/blob/master/src/person_follower.cpp) in c++. It uses geometry_msgs/Twist.h

I just want to publish in terminal the values from x, y, width and height.
However when I run the code I receive nothing.

This is the code that Im using

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import rospy
 from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

 def callback(data):
   rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)

 def listener():

# In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
# node are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
# anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
# name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
# run simultaneously.
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("commands", Twist, callback)

  # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      listener()
```

Hope you could give me a hand
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223785/creating-a-subscriber-in-python/) by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-11**:
Check the format of the commands topic - is it a Twist message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `Twist` message as no field named `data`. I know that you took this example from the python tutorial on subscribers. That tutorial use a [String.msg](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) as you can see this as a field named `data`. The [Twist.msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) as two data fields, linear and angular. which are [Vector3.msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Vector3.html)
which contain 3 float64 numbers. So to clear it up to get the 'X' value, you would do the following.

```
data.linear.x
```

---

Originally posted by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) with karma: 127 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s.vaichu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38233/s.vaichu/) on 2019-05-14**:
thanks a lot, it really helped me